# Make GetType match typeof base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a role provider to supply user role information to an ASP.NET MVC 4 framework I'm using a library called JDash. The JDash [documentation](http://www.jdash.net/docs/jdashnetmvcdevelopersguide.pdf) calls for me to write a provider implementing `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`, then set its type name in a JDash .config file. So I wrote a stub of my role provider and gave JDash its type name, and JDash found the setting properly and tried to instantiate my `RoleProvider`. However, it kept failing with:

> "Custom role provider must implement System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
>   abstract class"

Even though I was absolutely sure that my class was implementing `RoleProvider` properly.

So I took a look at the JDash source code and found how it's checking that the set role provider implements `RoleProvider`:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(config["roleProvider"]);
if (!(type == typeof (RoleProvider)))
      throw new ArgumentException("Custom role provider must implement System.Web.Security.RoleProvider abstract class");
```

The problem is, `GetType()` returns the actual runtime type of my role provider...which is not `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`, it's a class *derived* from `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`, so of course it doesn't match `typeof(RoleProvider)`. My class and `RoleProvider` are of different types; one just happens to be derived from the other, a fact that `typeof` happily ignores. So if I'm looking at this right, JDash has a bug that makes it impossible to give it a role provider that returns its runtime type as something other than RoleProvider.

I'll be reporting this bug and hoping for a fix, but for the time being, is there some way I can work around it? Could I somehow make `GetType("MyRoleProviderDerivedClass")` return the type of `RoleProvider`? Or can I trick `typeof` somehow, so that it thinks `MyRoleProviderDerivedClass` is the same as the `RoleProvider` base class?

Comment: Given that the fix is really simple (use `Type.IsAssignableFrom`) you could probably just fork while you're waiting for the fix...

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't properly have access to the JDash source code - I found that type checking bit by decompiling.

Comment: Urgh - had assumed this was open source. Not a lot you can do then, I suspect. That looks completely broken by design, to be honest.

Comment: Apologies for closing as a dupe, wasn't paying attention. That said, not really answerable other than to submit a bug report to the original developers.

Comment: Does `config["roleProvider"]` reference a configuration file, as the name suggests, perhaps as a kludgy way of dealing with precisely this issue (rather than just `IsAssignableFrom` with `RoleProvider`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way around this because you can't hook into the comparison or into `typeof`. This is a simple reference comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this is how it is. On a whim I tried writing a new MyRoleProvider.GetType() method to hide Object.GetType(), but that didn't help.

Comment: GetType is not virtual, nobody will call that new method. We don't want objects to be able to lie about their type.